# How to make awk escape the file separator =

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I need to compare difference between two files.
Consider the following files :

old1.properties file contains :

```
# comment
url=https://test.org/#,https://test.org:id=123
```

old2.properties file contains :

```
old-key1=value1
old-key3=value3
old-key4=value4
```

new1.properties file contains :

```
# comment
url=#
```

new2.properties file contains :

```
old-key1=value1
new-key2=value2
old-key3=value3
old-key4=value4
```

The result I want at the end:

First case :

```
# comment
url=https://test.org/#,https://test.org:id=123
```

Second case :

```
old-key1=value1
new-key2=value2
old-key3=value3
old-key4=value4
```

I used the following command:

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR {if ($2!="") a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a {$2=a[$1]} {print $0}' OFS== old.properties new.properties >old_new.txt
```

But the equals (=) which is inside the url is creating a problem.
I am getting:

```
url=https://test.org,https://test.org:id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk -F= 'NR==FNR {if ($2!="") a[$1]=$0; next}
   /^#/ {print; next}
   $1 in a {print a[$1]}
   !($1 in a)' old.properties new.properties

# comment
url=https://test.org/#,https://test.org:id=123
```

Comment: @anubhava thanks a lot !

And if I had comments how can I ignore them to keep them in the result ?
Ex : 
`# comment 1
url=https://test.org/#,https://test.org:id=123`

Comment: I have another case where the command no longer works.

If in the new file I have a newline in the middle. Example :
`new.properties
old key1=value1
new key2=value2
old key3=value3`
 
`old.properties:
old key1=value1
old key3=value3`

How I can get the newline in the output ?

Comment: Formatted text is not easy to read in comments. Can you edit your question and show this text there